# $.ajax() returns same value each time from server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3 for a website which has a very simple comment form which utilizes the jQuery `ajax()` method to communicate with the server. here is the snippet.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php/comments/publish_reply/',
    cache: false,
    data: $("form.actreply").serialize()
}).done(function(res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

It works fine and it successfully fetch all the information's from the server for the first time, but if i again submit the form with different content each and every time its fetching the old comment(the very first comment)!

I have double checked the server side issues and it seems there is no issue.

Here is the model that is used to fetch the current comment:

```
public function get_single_reply($time, $current_user_id)
{
    $data = $this->db->select('reply.*, users.u_id, users.u_name, users.u_status')
        ->from('reply')
        ->join('users', 'users.u_id = reply.reply_author_id')
        ->where([
            'reply.reply_date' => $time,
            'users.u_id' => $current_user_id
        ])
        ->limit(1,0)
        ->get()
        ->result();
    if ($data) return $data[0];
    else return false;
}
```

What is missing here?

*happy new year*

Comment: have you checked that server is recieving different data and responding with different data?.. you can debug your server responses by using google extensions like `Postman` or firefox extension like `HttpRequester`

Comment: Wild guess: You're using a MySQL database and sorting the comments by date, `ASC` instead of `DESC`.

Comment: @nosthertus Yes, the server is receiving different data

Comment: please update the question the relevant php/codeigniter bits of code

Comment: @AlexAndrei i have added the model in the question that retrieve the current comment, in order to send it back to browser.

Comment: what do you have in the database related to this `user_id`? does it populate properly? can you also update the question to include some rows from the table, the result of `show create table reply;` and the parameters that get sent with the ajax call ?

Comment: try to replicate your function in `MySQL` syntax and check if it returns what you look for.. from here i cannot say if server is really responding with different data

Comment: Turn off AJAX caching: `$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});`

Comment: What's missing is seeing how you get from `/index.php/comments/publish_reply/` to `get_single_reply(...)`

Comment: can you also show your ajax target method  publish_reply()

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your query fetch not current comment but the first comment for current date (if reply.reply_date is date). You should add `order by reply.reply_date desc` to make it work like expected.